# ATMega128 Output Flicker on Startup

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I'm using an ATMega128 micro and have all of my pin inits set to output and set to low under my main section of code:

```
PORTB=0x00;
DDRB=0xFF;
```

However on startup, the output associated with PORTB.0 flicks high for a split second (I've caught it on the scope) and it seems the other outputs are doing the same. Seems like it goes LOW-HIGH-LOW. I've done some reading that it could be caused by the tri-state to output switch during startup, so I've set the PUD register to 1 before the pin inits and then back to 0 after and still no luck. Does anyone have any other ideas to keep that output off during startup?  It doesn't always occur either which is what has me stumped.

Comment: Do you have bias resistors?

Comment: Well done at least for writing the port data before configuring as an output.

Comment: This is almost certainly a hardware question rather then a software issue and you should post it on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  GPIO are high-impedance inputs on reset, and the level measured with a scope will depend on the circuitry connected to the pin.  If it is an issue and you require a specific level on start-up, use a pull-up or pull-down resistor - that is the level must be externally asserted because the input will not drive it - it is floating.

Comment: @WeatherVane are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @Clifford it's a board my employer has used for years. On the backside of it there is a transistor used to turn on a relay. That relay is wrecking havok currently on my system since it's not supposed to turn on after reset. I had read what you said about them being tristate on reset, just wasn't sure if there's a way to be sure software wise that the pins are always low after being set. Since it's intermittent your reply makes very good sense...I just can't change the hardware on the board easily at all.

Comment: With respect to being *sarcastic*; I think he was simply saying that it is a good practice that many fail to observe (and could cause the pin to be momentarily driven incorrectly if done the other way around (sub microsecond glitch).  Your best bet is to configure the GPIO as early as possible in the start-up by modifying the start-up code that runs from the reset vector before C run-time start-up (most probably in assembly code) - the relay is unlikely to be able to react in time in that case.

Comment: @Clifford I couldn't tell if he was being sarcastic or not and saying it was a bad practice...it is the internet. As for that, I'll start looking into the assembler and see what I can figure out. We use CodeVisionAVR for our AVR stuff...it's not the best thing in the world.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. No sarcasm was intended at all, just an observation of good practice on the software side by writing the required output state before enabling the port as output. As for the hardware, nobody here knows the board is an established product or one that was put together without realising that the outputs will float unless/until driven.

Comment: *I just can't change the hardware on the board easily at all.* It is not unusual to see a board mod. If necessary, a pull-down resistor is not very difficult. Another suggestion on the software side, is if this is newly written code, perhaps the port configuration can be done at the very earliest opportunity (if it was left until later, maybe after some delays required for other configuration).

Comment: I've got the port inits right after the main declaration. There isn't much room ahead of that. And the issue with making a board mod is that we use this same board on 3 of our products and our usage is very low...I'm talking like <100/year (across all of our products that use it). So it's impractical to make a mod for a very low quantity if there is something I can do software wise.

Comment: Does your microcontroller have an internal pull down you can enable?

Comment: @Colin__s :  While that may be the case, it does not solve the problem; the problem is the length of time it remains configured as an input.

Comment: @wgdvs : There is  a great deal of code that runs between the reset vector and `main()` and it execution time will be dependent on a number of factors including the amount of static data to be initialised.

Comment: With the information provided in comments it is possible to provide a software related answer to this question.  You should update the question with this information rather than leaving it in comments.  The relevant information is the use of CodeVisionAVR, the fact that you are driving a relay, details of the connection to that relay and the fact that you are performing the initialisation at the start of `main()`.  Also of relevance would be the type of relay (electro-mechanical or solid-state) and the length of the of the pulse observed on the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is a hardware issue - lack of a pull-down resistor on the GPIO so that it is floating when in the reset-default high-impedance input state.

The best you can do in software is to initialise the GPIO at the earliest opportunity immediately after the reset.  To do this in CodeVisionAVR you need to use a customised startup.asm in your project as described in section 4.18 of the CoadeVisionAVR compiler manual:

[image]...

Where I suggest you initialise PORTB and DDRB as follows:

```
             LDI    R16,  0x00       
             OUT    PORTB, R16 
             LDI    R16,  0xFF       
             OUT    DDRB, R16
```

immediately before step 2, i.e. the first four instructions.  The amount of time the GPIO will be left floating will possibly be too small for the relay to react if it is a mechanical relay.  You may still have a problem for a solid state relay.  The length of any pulse may depend on the power-supply rise time; if it is slow, you may get a longer pulse.

Comment: I did this and everything seems all good. I actually did this myself last night and didn't have time to check back in here on this, but this is what worked. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @wgdvs : Cool; my answer used information you have currently only provided in comments; if you could update the question it would make it more coherent and useful for the SO community.

Comment: Will do. And actually it helped, but hooking it up to a cycler I still cought the issue in about 1 out of every 80 tries...I told my boss the really only good fix is to put a pull down on that pin to GND. He agreed and has approved the change. It shouldn't effect any of our products since that pin only controls this one relay in all cases.